# Subtracting Missing[] the old way

Tags: conversion, missing

In previous versions of Mathematica Missing[]- Missing[] would output 
Missing[]- Missing[]. In the current version is outputs 0. Is there a way to get Mathematica to revert back to the old output? The new implementation is reeking havoc with my archival code.

Comment: `Missing` was introduced in 10.0.  I just verified that in 10.0.2, `Missing[]-Missing[]` evaluates to `0`.  `Missing[] + Missing[]` evaluates to `2 Missing[]`. I have not used `Missing` much, but as I remember it never behaved specially with arithmetic (like `Indeterminate`  and `Undefined` do).

Comment: Perhaps what you mean is that `Dataset` handles `Missing` specially, and causes the arithmetic results you are referring to.   `Missing[]` itself doesn't have special properties, and doesn't evaluate specially outside of `Dataset`.  If you see changed behaviour *with* `Dataset`, please show an example in the question.

Comment: For example, in 11.2, `ds = Dataset[{1, Missing[], 2}]; ds[# - #&] // Normal` results in `{0, Missing["Indeterminate"], 0}` and not `{0, 0, 0}`.  I.e. the special behaviour *inside* `Dataset` is still present and works as before.

Comment: Replacing Missing with Indeterminate solve a whole bunch of issues.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72131/discussion-on-question-by-wintermute-subtracting-missing-the-old-way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Unprotect[Missing];
Missing /: Plus[a_Missing, b__] := Indeterminate
Protect[Missing];
```

Your example:

```
Missing[] - Missing[]
```

> Indeterminate

**Addendum**

In addition to the approaches in the comments, you could also [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) [`Missing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing) when performing computations. For example:

```
SetAttributes[missingArithmetic, HoldFirst];

missingArithmetic[expr_] := Block[{Missing = Indeterminate&},
    expr
]
```

Examples:

```
missingArithmetic[Missing[]-Missing[]]
missingArithmetic[1-Missing[]]
missingArithmetic[Sin[Missing[]]/Sin[Missing[]]]
```

> Indeterminate
>
> Indeterminate
>
> Indeterminate

Comment: But what about `1 - Missing[]`? Sorry, couldn't resist :-)

Comment: You're right, that's a case where UpValues won't work.

Comment: But you can add an UpValue to `Times`.  However, it gets messy quickly, as it is unclear what set of functions should be considered.

Comment: How about `Missing /: head_Symbol[___, _Missing, ___] := Indeterminate /; MemberQ[Attributes[head], NumericFunction]`?  It does feel dangerous and I imagine it might have a noticeable performance impact ... I haven't tested.  But it does work even on `Sin[Missing[]]`.

Comment: or   ``Missing /: (_?System`Dump`HeldNumericFunctionQ)[___,  _Missing, ___] := Indeterminate``?